# Regex match multiple occurrences of same pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to run a test to see if a long string with multiple lines has multiple occurrences of the same pattern, or lets say 5 or 10 occurrences.

So a string like:

```
$string = "this is a test pattern1 more of a test pattern1

and so on and so on pattern1";
```

So in this case I was trying in PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/(pattern1)\1{2,}/m',$string)) print "Found 2+ occurrences of pattern1\n";
```

Of course this does not work.

And I cannot use `preg_match_all`.

Can someone correct my regex please?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you was not far from the good pattern *(for three occurrences here)*:

```
/(pattern1)(?:.*?\1){2,}/s
```

where the s modifier allows the dot to match newlines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No, I have written an example for three occurrences. You  will avoid many backtracking, if you use a lazy quantifier instead of a greedy quantifier.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: it's only an example, at the begining of the post he wrote 5, 10

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following..

```
if (preg_match('/(pattern1)(?:((?!\1).)*\1){2,}/s', $string)) {
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/168274)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure how this differs from Casimir's answer, but I appreciate the response. Max

Answer (score 1):

Check this pattern

```
/(pattern1)/g
```

g - modifier finds all matches instead of returning first match.

Comment: useless, please see its for php and with preg_match there is no modifier such as `g`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you simply search for the word/pattern using preg_match_all and count the number of occurences :

```
<?php
$message="this is a test pattern1 more of a test pattern1 and one more pattern1";
echo preg_match_all('/pattern1/i', $message, $matches);
```

will return `3`.

or rather in your case:

```
<?php
$message="this is a test pattern1 more of a test pattern1 and one more pattern1";
if(preg_match_all('/pattern1/i', $message, $matches) >= 2 ) print "Found 2+ occurences of pattern1\n";
```

Comment: OP stated he/she can not use `preg_match_all`  ^^^^

Comment: oh, yes, but now I am thinking what might be the possible reason for not using preg_match_all when you require one

Comment: I can't use preg_match_all because I'm just using php to test. This is for a SpamAssassin rule. Max